# How to describe a person with the qualities give in the body of this question?

Tags: word-choice

Which term can be used to describe a person who usually does his works by his own, for example, repairs his car himself, learns through self-studying, etc. (I look for something more specific or specialized term than "independent")

Comment: "***Self-reliant***"?

Comment: Much may depend on whether you're looking for a *positive* term (you admire the person's self-reliance), or a *negative* one (you think he should stick to what he's good at, and not try to rewire his own house or perform brain surgery on his own sick child).

Comment: @DanBron I guess it's really close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed I look for a positive term, however I think it would be great if someone mentions the opposite as well.

Answer (score 4):

One word 
:  [Autodidact](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/autodidact) : a self-taught person.

*Auto- means "**self**" and "didact" comes from the Greek word for "**teach**.*

> If you're an **autodidact** you've done most of your learning on your
>   own.

Answer (score 0):

An [amateur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur) may have  those skills:

> - is generally considered a person attached to a particular pursuit, study, or science in a non-professional or unpaid manner. Amateurs often have little or no formal training in their pursuits, and many are autodidacts (self-taught).

Answer (score 0):

In situations where teamwork is required (e.g. many software engineering firms), a positive term for someone who is *able* to work on their own when needed might be "**self-starter**" (a term which admittedly has become somewhat cliched in the corporate world).  A person who is unable to work with others and *solely* works on their own might be referred to in a negative context as a "**cowboy**" or even a "**loner**", though the latter is rarely used, as it has connotations about the person's ability to interact socially that the former term does not.

Occasionally I have heard of "cowboy" being used for software engineers in a positive light, but much more frequently it is used in a derogatory fashion, implying the person is unwilling to work with others, follow rules or methodologies, or consider others' opinions or needs.

Merriam-Webster: **cowboy** 3. one having qualities (as recklessness, aggressiveness, or independence) popularly associated with cowboys

Answer (score -1):

A *jack-of-all-trades* is someone who is capable of doing a wide variety of jobs or possesses a wide variety of skills. This phrase can be used positively, but it may have negative connotations as a longer version of the phrase is "Jack of all trades, master of none," implying that someone can do a little bit of many things without actually excelling at any of them. More positive terms are *polymath* and *Renaissance man.*

Comment: Nice one, but a "jack-of-all-trades" (master of none) is a person who, indeed, can do a lot of different things, but is not necessarily doing very well in any of these, so this expression is expected to have a negative nuance.

Comment: Yes, I said it may have negative connotations. However, it's also used more broadly to mean the more neutral "someone who has a wide variety of skills."